# How to avoid validations on apex.page.submit

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

[image]I have a select list, on whose change, a few items are to be made readonly. For this, on change of the select list , i am submitting the page using the below JS call

`apex.page.submit({request:"REQ_TYPE",showWait: true});`

According to the documentation. This call shouldn't validate any page items. But it turns out it is throwing "Value required" validation.

I need to pass the request value to make sure other process on pre-rendering doesnot trigger after submit - on reload.

Though default is *false* for the validate key. I tried setting it to false as below:

`apex.page.submit({request:"REQ_TYPE", showWait:true, validate:false});`

Even that didn't help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the validate parameter to false.

```
apex.page.submit({request:"REQ_TYPE", showWait:true, validate:false});
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aexjs/apex.page.html#.submit

Comment: I even tried that by explicitly defining the validate key as false.But same result.

Comment: Strange. I've tested this now on apex.oracle.com and as you have seen, it doesn't work. I don't know why - it should. Even the declarative Execute Validations = No and Always Execute = No combination, which should cause a validation to be skipped, still causes the validation to fire. Think I'll raise this on the oracle community forum.

Comment: FWIW, if you have a button that does a Submit, if you set Execute Validations = No, the validation doesn't fire.

Comment: Thanks Kemp - for confirming. Would be better if it gets fixed from the Oracle end.

Answer (score -1):

in the item attribute change the value required to NO

Comment: Thats a required field. I just want to enforce readonly condition on other page items based on the value of the select list. For that i want to submit the page without validating anything.

Answer (score -1):

Like Mohamed answered, you should change the required attribute to No. This will disable the default validation that is pestering you.
Instead, make a custom validation, that, depending on the value of your select list, will check the other items.